# How to change default source version for secondary source for Codebuild in terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codebuild

i have a codebuild project defined in terraform, it has a secondary source and i'd like to specify a default branch to it (not master, but using a feature branch)

From [Terraform doc](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/codebuild_project), looks like we can specify a variable called `source_version =`, but is this just for the primary source? i don't want to change the source version for primary source, only for the secondary source, is there a way to do so?

Thanks.

Comment: I am unsure if the API/provider for Codebuild supports multiple sources. I know for sure the API/provider for Codepipeline supports that.

Answer (score 0):

See `secondary_source_version` in the [Terraform provider for AWS](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/5.35.0/docs/resources/codebuild_project#secondary_source_version)